# Using same then/catch/finally blocks for two promises of different types

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

I have the following operations:

```
class CreateObjectOperation {
    // ...

    func promise() -> Promise<Object>
}

class DeleteObjectOperation {
    // ...

    func promise() -> Promise<Void>
}
```

I want to be able to use the same `then/catch/finally` blocks for both. I tried the following:

```
let foo: Bool = ...
firstly {
    (foo ?
        CreateObjectOperation().promise() :
        DeleteObjectOperation().promise()
    ) as Promise<AnyObject>
}.then { _ -> Void in
    // ...
}.finally {
    // ...
}.catch { error in
    // ...
}
```

but this does not compile. Is there any working solution (apart from moving the code from blocks to separate functions, which I would like to avoid)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
firstly { _ -> Promise<Void>
    (foo ?
        CreateObjectOperation().promise().then { _ in Promise<Void>() } :
        DeleteObjectOperation().promise()
    ) as Promise<AnyObject>
}.then { _ -> Void in
    // ...
}
```